# How to convert/get the value of integer expression in cplex?

Tags: type-conversion, integer, overlap, cplex, docplex

I am new to Cplex. I need to compute the overlap between several intervals at same time. For that, i compute the overlap_length between two intervals at a time, and i save the max and min of the start/end points.
For example, let's consider three intervals vars I1, I2, I3. The objective is to maximize the overlap between the three.
Then, the code is as follow:

> over1=mdl.overlap_length(I1,I2)
>
> start1=max(mdl.start_of(I1),mdl.start_of(I2))
>
> end1=min(mdl.end_of(I1),mdl.end_of(I2))
>
> over1=mdl.overlap_length(I3,(start1,end1)

And then i maximize the over1.
With that, i get the following error:

*AssertionError: To express a fixed interval, 'interval2' should be a tuple of two integers*

In fact, the start1 and end1 are CP integer expressions. I didn't find a way to convert or to get the value!
Is there anyone who have an idea how to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In your last line start1 and end1 needs to be bounds, they need to be values not decision variables. So as a workaround, you could rely on an artificial interval.

since OPL is very close to docplex but IMHO opinion [easier](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) let me show you the way in OPL.

```
using CP;

dvar interval I1 in 0..20;
dvar interval I2 in 0..20;
dvar interval I3 in 0..20;

dvar int over1;
dvar int start1;
dvar int end1;

dvar interval artificialInterval;

maximize over1;

subject to
{

    over1==overlapLength(I1,I2);

    start1==maxl(startOf(I1),startOf(I2));

    end1==minl(endOf(I1),endOf(I2));

    startOf(artificialInterval)==start1;
    endOf(artificialInterval)==end1;

    over1==overlapLength(I3,artificialInterval);
}
```

works fine

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to implement your proposition but in docplex i canno't assign the values startOf(artificialInterval)==start1; so ihave tried to add it as aconstraint and it doesn't work...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071915/how-to-initiate-the-interval-variable-bounds-in-docplex-python/60074141#60074141